# Iterating over an `OrderedDict` and deleting some of its keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have an `OrderedDict` `od` with integer keys and integer values. I want to iterate over `od` and delete elements of `od` based on the value I find. Basically what I want to achieve is:

```
od = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 5}

for key in od:
    del od[key]
```

In the end I want `od` to be equal to `{1: 2, 3: 5}`. Python does not allow to change the size of an `OrderedDict` during its iteration. Is it possible to overcome this problem?

I am working with Python 3.5

Comment: @f5r5e5d the answer clarifies that, specifically saying that you can use `items` for `3.x`

Answer (score 5):

That is because you can not modify the length of `dict` while you are iterating over it. Instead you have to iterate over the copy of list of keys within the `dict` as:

```
# For both Python 3.x and 2.7
>>> for key in list(od):
...     del od[key]
...
>>> od
{}
```

However in Python2.7, one may even use `dict.keys()` to get the same behavior:

```
# In Python 2.7
>>> for key in od.keys():
...     del od[key]
...
>>> od
{}
```

Comment: `list(od)` should work in Python 2 or 3. I'm not entirely sure, but I think `dict.keys` is just a holdover from a very old version of Python that didn't support general iteration, and `keys()` was the only way to get the keys of a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

this is the easiest way i know. enjoy!

With `dicts`, you can't change the length of the dictionary. however, what you can do is make a list copy of the original dictionary and use that to iterate through the original dictionary. as shown below

```
od = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}



for key in list(od):
        if key == 'b':
            print(key)
            del od[key]
            print(od)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you mean to do

```
od = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 5}

for key in od.copy():                 # iterate over a copy
    if key in od and od[key] in od:   # check for both key, 'target' key
        del od[od[key]]               # then delete the target with indirect indexing 

od
Out[52]: {1: 2, 3: 5}
```